# how to sort the contents of CLOB field

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table and some fields are `CLOB` type and the content in the `CLOB` was delimited by some separator such as `'|'` and usually the content in the filed looks like this : `name2|name1|name3...`, actually the length of the content is more than 40000 characters, so is there any way to `sort the content by asc`? I want to look the content like this: `name1|name2|name3...`

can any body help me?

Answer (score 2):

If it's even remotely possible, I'd strongly suggest you change your data model - add a details table for the names. This will solve you a *lot* of pain in the future.

Anyhow, if you absolutely need to store a pipe-separated list of names in your CLOB field, I'd suggest this approach:

- break the CLOB into separate rows (using a pipelined function)
- sort the rows
- aggregate the rows into a new CLOB

A (somewhat naive and untested) implementation of this approach:

```
create type stringtabletype as table of varchar2(4000);

create or replace function split_CLOB(p_Value     in CLOB,
                                      p_Separator in varchar2 default '|')
  return stringtabletype
  pipelined as
  l_Offset number default 1;
  l_Str    varchar2(4000);
  idx      number;
begin
  idx := dbms_lob.instr(lob_loc => p_Value,
                        pattern => p_Separator,
                        offset  => l_Offset);
  dbms_output.put_line(idx);
  while (idx > 0)
  loop
    l_Str := dbms_lob.substr(p_Value,
                             idx - l_Offset,
                             l_Offset);
    pipe row(l_Str);
    l_Offset := idx+1;
    idx      := dbms_lob.instr(p_Value,
                               p_Separator,
                               l_Offset);
    dbms_output.put_line(idx);
  end loop;
  -- pipe remainder of string
  l_Str := dbms_lob.substr(p_Value,
                           dbms_lob.getlength(p_Value) - l_Offset + 1,
                           l_Offset);
  pipe row(l_str);
  return;
end;

create or replace function sort_stringtabletype(p_Values in stringtabletype)
  return stringtabletype as
  l_Result stringtabletype;
begin
  select column_value bulk collect
    into l_Result
    from table(p_Values)
   order by column_value;
  return l_Result;
end;

create or replace function stringtabletype_to_CLOB(p_Values    in stringtabletype,
                                                   p_Separator in varchar2 default '|')
  return CLOB as
  l_Result CLOB;
begin
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_Result, false);
  for i in 1 .. p_Values.count - 1
  loop
    dbms_lob.writeappend(l_Result,
                         length(p_Values(i)),
                         p_Values(i));
    dbms_lob.writeappend(l_Result,
                         length(p_Separator),
                         p_Separator);
  end loop;
  dbms_lob.writeappend(l_Result,
                       length(p_Values(p_Values.count)),
                       p_Values(p_Values.count));
  return l_Result;
end;
```

Example usage:

```
select stringtabletype_to_CLOB (
  sort_stringtabletype(
    split_CLOB('def|abc|ghic', '|')
  )
) from dual
```

You could then use an UPDATE statement like

```
  update my_table
   set clob_field = stringtabletype_to_CLOB (
      sort_stringtabletype(
        split_CLOB(my_table, '|')
      )
```